# Probability of tagged individuals

Tags: probability

If there are $20$ tagged cows in a field of $200$, and I take $10$ cows (no replacement), what is the probability of exactly $2$ cows being tagged? 
Is this a binomial distribution, where $P = 0.1$ (tag), $Q = 0.9$ (no tag) and it's $\binom{10}{2} 0.1^ 2 0.9 ^ 8$?
How would a simulation in R with `sample` be?
Thanks!

Comment: It's not binomial because of the no replacement condition.  (So probability is not the same from one trial to the next.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was with replacement, then yes it would be the binomial distribution, since each selection of a cow would be independent of the next.

Unfortunately, without replacement you have to do this combinatorially:
$$\frac{\text{number of ways to choose 10 cows with exactly 2 tagged}}{\text{number of ways to choose 10 cows}}$$

**Number of ways to choose 10 cows**

> $\binom{200}{10}$

**Number of ways to choose 10 cows with exactly 2 tagged**

> $\binom{20}{2} \binom{180}{8}$

---

Here is some R code that creates a vector of $180$ zeros and $20$ ones, and chooses $10$ entries randomly without replacement.

```
v=c(rep(0,180),rep(1,20))
sample(v,10,replace=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, since when you take out a cow, the prob of taking a tagged one is different.